# Javascript remove null value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My requirement is to remove null value in an array.

I have an array like the following way

```
addresses = {
    status: true
    accounts: [6]
    0: {
        account_id: "100004069844270facebook"
        account_name: "Lal Mohan T"
        account_type: "facebook"
    } -
        1: {
            account_id: "bdc33d8ca941b8f00c2a4e046ba44761twitter"
            account_name: "Minu Jose"
            account_type: "twitter"
    } -
        2: {
            account_id: "ec466c09fd62993ade48c6c4bb8d2da7facebook"
            account_name: "Jijo John"
            account_type: "facebook"
    } -
        3: {
            account_id: "138115932930527facebook"
            account_name: "TVInfo AMT"
            account_type: "facebook"
    }
    4: {}
    5: {}
    6: {}
}
```

How to remove the {} elements from this array.

I have tried array filter but its not working in my case

```
 addresses = addresses .filter(function (n) { return n !== undefined });
```

Please help me to solve this issue, your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That is not an `undefined` value.

Comment: There are no arrays in that object.

Comment: @MihaiStancu How to remove {} value ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what the object's actual structure is, because that's not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove elements from accounts that actually aren't accounts (but empty) you should test for a property of an account instead of the element itself.

```
accounts = accounts.filter(function (n) { return n.account_id !== undefined });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're neither dealing with `null` values nor with `undefined` values. It seems like you're having an object, which contains other objects. Some of those contained objects maybe empty and you would need to explicitly check for that:

```
Object.keys( addresses ).filter(function( v ) {
   return typeof addresses[ v ] !== 'object' || Object.keys( addresses[ v ] ).length !== 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `addresses` is no array, it's an object ( `{}` = object, `[]` = array ).

`{}` does not mean `undefined`, but its an empty object. Easiest way to test if its empty is using `Object.keys()` inside your filter method

```
function( value ) { return !(typeof value === "object" && Object.keys( value ).length === 0 ); }
```